# Forming a expression of quadratic equation involving polygons

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Six congruent isosceles triangles with equal sides $x$ cm are removed from the six corners of a paper in the shape of a regular hexagon of sides 20cm . The remaining portion is in the shoe of a 12 sided regular polygon.

Write down two expressions, in terms of x, for the length of a side of the 12 sided regular polygon .

I am only able to come up with one which is

$ x = 20 - x $

Can I get a hint for the other one ? Thanks in advance ..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be the side of the regular $12$-gon (called a dodecagon, I believe). If we look at one side of the original hexagon, we see the middle portion has length $y$ and each end is a side of the isosceles triangle, which is $x$. You say that original hexagon has sides of length $20$. Therefore,

$$x+y+x=20$$

Now look at the isosceles triangle. The equal sides are $x$, the base is $y$, and the angle between the equal sides is $120°$ (since the inside angle of a regular hexagon has measure $120°$). Using the law of cosines,

$$y^2=x^2+x^2-2xx\cos 120°$$

Solve each of those two equations for $y$ and you have your desired expressions.